# How can I run a 12v 19a pump with solar panels without using battery?

Tags: dc-motor, solar-energy

I have an water pump of 12v 19a৳  I want to run it with solar panels without using battery৳ I am ready to expend money to buy controller or othre parts৳

Note: At present i use a 12v 25a adaptor to run the pump৳

Comment: but not for a battery? It's the simplest way to buffer up some energy to ensure you can actually run it for a bit.

Comment: Use a battery and charge controller. The battery will supply the relatively large (much more than 19A) starting current. It can be relatively small and probably cheaper than a suitable capacitor. You'll need some way to disconnect it when the solar cells aren't charging.

Answer (score 0):

19 amperes at 12 volts is 228 watts. That's a big solar panel altough not impossible. The starting of the motor needs much more than 19 amperes, but not a long time.

You must test how big buffer capacitor is needed to make the reliable starting possible. It is a replacement of a battery just for the startup. Unfortunately it does not help at night nor when it's cloudy.

Comment: It doesn't need a lot more if it's made to soft start.  It may be cheaper to get a soft start motor than have a ton of extra panels.

Comment: @Harper The water punp is what it is and the questioner asked how to supply it. I believe that a capacitor is a possible solution. Maybe the one that is used by car stereo "geniuses" who can be heard a few house blocks away.

Comment: Maxell ultracap, sure, good solution.  Just the same, "the load is what it is" does not apply to solar, the load is always negotiable.

Answer (score 0):

Solar never exists all by itself except for experiments.

For real projects you must design a solar power **system**.

This consists, at the very least, a battery, a charge controller, solar panels, and a load connected to the battery.

---

To answer your question directly, you could use something else to store energy other than a battery.  Like, say, use the panels to run another pump that fills a cistern with water.  Then the water can come out and turn a generator at a controlled rate to run your pump.  Voila, a solar system without an electric battery.

See what I'm getting at?  You simply MUST have some sort of storage that can meter out the electricity to your pump.  Trying to do it without a normal battery will require a rube-goldberg type of setup due to the fluctuating amount of sunlight the panels will receive.  They have no inherent way to guarantee a certain consistent amount of energy all by themselves.